The problem is that if i add one item, while trying to add another item, the first one i added will disappear. How do i solve it?
class FoodRestaurant:
    """
    Build a food ordering and delivery system using python 
    lists and dictionaries as storage, store your products 
    permanently in csv file.
    """
    def __init__(self,types_of_food,price_of_food,availability_of_food):
        """constructor method"""
        self.types_of_food = types_of_food
        self.price_of_food = price_of_food
        self.availability_of_food = availability_of_food
        
        self.add_products = [
            ['Types of Food','Price of Food','availability of Food'],
            ['okpa',2000,10],
            ['rice',1500,20],
            ['akpu',1200,9],
            ['maize',1000,10],
        ]


    def main(self):
        """main function"""
        self._ordering_food()
        self._delivering_food()
        self.view_all_products()
        self.update_product_status()
        self._adding_products()
        self.delete_product()
        self.view_single_product()
        
        

    
    def _adding_products(self):
        """Adding food items to a list"""
        self.types_of_food = input("Enter Food Type: ")
        if len(self.types_of_food) <= 2:
            print("Enter a valid food type")
            return False
        else:
            self.price_of_food = int(input("Enter Food Price: "))
            self.availability_of_food = int(input("Enter Food Availability: "))
            admin = {}
            admin['type of food'] = self.types_of_food
            admin['price of food'] = self.price_of_food
            admin['availability of food'] = self.availability_of_food
            self.add_products.append(admin)
            print(self.add_products)
            print("Added Successfully")

I created a list with some items in the List. I added a new item in the list and it appears, but if I try to add another item, the one I added earlier will disappear. What I am expecting is that if I add a new item, while trying to add another item, the first one I added should not disappear.

Can you add some example code showing how you're adding things to your list showing the issue?

And are you using mylist.append(item) to add to the list?

By looking at the method def _adding_products, you will see input() methods of how the food types,price of food and availability of food were used to be adding items by appending to self.add_products that has other items. That is how i use to add item to the list.

Yes, am using the appending method to add item to the list

A key part of every question is a minimal reproducible example. Your example is neither minimal nor reproducible. I need to be able to run your code at my PC and to reproduce your problem to be able to help you. Please remember it.

In general, you shouldn't use instance varables for local variables in a function. There's no reason for types_of_food, price_of_food, and availability_of_food to be in self.

There are a few issue in your code, or few things that I didn't understand:

Why do you store the all the data in the class when they are already in the list? For me, all this is not used and already stored for each element in your list

   def __init__(self):
        """
            self.types_of_food = types_of_food
            self.price_of_food = price_of_food
            self.availability_of_food = availability_of_food
            Not needed 
        """
        self.add_products = [
            ['Types of Food','Price of Food','availability of Food'],
            ['okpa',2000,10],
            ['rice',1500,20],
            ['akpu',1200,9],
            ['maize',1000,10],
        ]


You're adding a dictionary into a list In a list looking like this:

[['Types of Food','Price of Food','availability of Food'],
['okpa',2000,10],
['rice',1500,20],
['akpu',1200,9],
['maize',1000,10]]

you are adding a dict {'type of food': 'Pizza', 'price of food': 12, 'availability of food': 123}. A corrected version of the add_function where we add a list and don't save value twice can be implemented like this:
    def _adding_products(self):
        """Adding food items to a list"""
        new_product = [input("Enter Food Type: ")]
        if len(new_product[0]) <= 2:
            print("Enter a valid food type")
            return False
        else:
            new_product.append(int(input("Enter Food Price: ")))
            new_product.append(int(input("Enter Food Availability: ")))
            self.add_products.append(new_product)
            print(self.add_products)
            print("Added Successfully")


Using a dict can also be a great idea in order to reach the desired food faster but you'll need to update your init
